# Detecting if an email is a "Delivery Status Notification" and extract information - Python

Tags: python, email

I'm using the Python `email` module to parse emails.

I need to be able to tell if an email is a "Delivery Status Notification", find out what the status is, and extract information on the email that failed, eg. the Subject.

The object I get after parsing with .parsestr(email) is like this:

```
{'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'quoted-printable',
 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1',
 'Date': 'Mon, 14 Mar 2011 11:26:24 +0000',
 'Delivered-To': 'sender@gmail.com',
 'From': 'Mail Delivery Subsystem <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com>',
 'MIME-Version': '1.0',
 'Message-ID': '<000e08jf90sd9f00e6f943f@google.com>',
 'Received': 'by 10.142.13.8 with SMTP id 8cs63078wfm;\r\n        Mon, 14 Mar 2011 04:26:24 -0700 (PDT)',
 'Return-Path': '<>',
 'Subject': 'Delivery Status Notification (Failure)',
 'To': 'sender@gmail.com',
 'X-Failed-Recipients': 'recipient@gmail.com'}
```

**Firstly**, how do I tell that this is a DSN without using a regexp on the subject?

**Secondly**, <strike>how do I access the body of the email</strike>, and information such as the error that was returned by the mail server?

**edit:** worked out I need to use `.get_payload()` to get the contents of the message.

The [email docs](http://docs.python.org/library/email#differences-from-mimelib) say:

> *The Parser class has no differences in its public interface. **It does
>   have some additional smarts to
>   recognize message/delivery-status type
>   messages**, which it represents as a
>   Message instance containing separate
>   Message subparts for each header block
>   in the delivery status notification*

---

### Update:

Basically, I need to be able to reliable detect that an email is a DSN, and then also to extract the original message so I can parse that with email.Parser() and get information about it.

Comment: For those who read this question but use .NET:  There is a Bounce class that uses a variety of tests to detect NDRs, though it's not foolproof:  http://www.limilabs.com/blog/bounce-handling

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The docs you cited says](http://docs.python.org/library/email#differences-from-mimelib) that the message is multi-part if it is [DSN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1894.html):

```
import email

msg = email.message_from_string(emailstr)

if (msg.is_multipart() and len(msg.get_payload()) > 1 and 
    msg.get_payload(1).get_content_type() == 'message/delivery-status'):
    # email is DSN
    print(msg.get_payload(0).get_payload()) # human-readable section
    
    for dsn in msg.get_payload(1).get_payload():
        print('action: %s' % dsn['action']) # e.g., "failed", "delivered"
        
    if len(msg.get_payload()) > 2:
        print(msg.get_payload(2)) # original message
```

#### Format of a Delivery Status Notification (from [rfc 3464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464#page-7)):

```
A DSN is a MIME message with a top-level content-type of
multipart/report (defined in [REPORT]).  When a multipart/report
content is used to transmit a DSN:

(a) The report-type parameter of the multipart/report content is
    "delivery-status".

(b) The first component of the multipart/report contains a human-
    readable explanation of the DSN, as described in [REPORT].

(c) The second component of the multipart/report is of content-type
    message/delivery-status, described in section 2.1 of this
    document.

(d) If the original message or a portion of the message is to be
    returned to the sender, it appears as the third component of the
    multipart/report.
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't rely on those tests as often DSNs will not be multipart, and will not have `content-type 'message/delivery-status'`, for example Gmail DSNs.

Comment: @Acorn: If it is not multipart it must not call itself a DSN according to rfc 1894.

Comment: @Sebastian: [Here's the raw message I get from google](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/cAlY6QEUvBbMd84jcMo7/). No sign of `"delivery-status"` and when I parse it into a python `Message` object it is not multipart.

Comment: @Acorn: It is easy to parse the google's message as is but it is not a DSN as the current standard rfc 3464 describes it.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Standards are beautiful, but in real world we want to detect DSN, no matter if it complies with RFC. As I've tested it, not many DSNs comply with this standard (one I've seen is my server, but that's about it).

Comment: @Tomasz Struczyński: I agree. I've mentioned the rfc to specify what `DSN` means exactly. Otherwise "DSN" has no more meaning than SPAM or porn i.e., even a human can't reliably classify it in all cases. Although there could be a "good-enough" approach for any particular application.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use Python but I suppose Gmail improved its support to DSN because my tests are successfull:

You can see in the sample below this is a multipart message with "Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status".

The way I identify reliably that it is a DSN:

- The first row is "Return-path: <>"
- Content-Type is "multipart/report" with "report-type=delivery-status"

Then, I know that:

- The report content is in the part with Content-Type = "message/delivery-status"
- Status and Action fields are always present in the report content.
- Note the Status field can be less precise than other status eventually present in the Diagnostic-Code field (not mandatory). However, the sample below is good (same status in all fields)
- The original message is in the part with Content-Type = "message/rfc822". Sometimes, MTA returns only original message headers without content. In this case, Content-Type is "text/rfc822-headers".

Sample DSN received after an e-mail sent to test-dsn-failure@gmail.com:

```
Return-path: <>
Received: from xxx ([xxx])
    by xxx with ESMTP; Fri, 04 May 2012 16:18:13 +0200
From: <Mailer-Daemon@xxx> (Mail Delivery System)
To: xxx
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 15:25:09 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
 boundary="HTB3nt3RR7vw/QMPR4kDPbKg+XWjXIKdC/rfHQ=="

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--HTB3nt3RR7vw/QMPR4kDPbKg+XWjXIKdC/rfHQ==
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to <postmaster@xxx>

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

<test-dsn-failure@gmail.com>: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 t12si10077186weq.36


--HTB3nt3RR7vw/QMPR4kDPbKg+XWjXIKdC/rfHQ==
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; xxx
Arrival-Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 15:25:09 +0200

Final-Recipient: rfc822; test-dsn-failure@gmail.com
Status: 5.1.1
Action: failed
Last-Attempt-Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 15:25:09 +0200
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 t12si10077186weq.36

--HTB3nt3RR7vw/QMPR4kDPbKg+XWjXIKdC/rfHQ==
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

[original message...]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `X-Failed-Recipients` header seems to be the quickest way to identify gmail DSN.  After that, it seems you must parse the text/plain content.

Comment: X-Failed-Recipients is only in few DSN

Comment: @guettli, but it appears to be fairly consistent in GMail DSN's, which is what my comment was directed to, and also appears to be from the OP example what is being used.  X-Failed-Recipients seems to show up on any "Failure" GMail DSN, but not a "Delay".

Comment: One would assume this header would not be present for mail delivery failures caused by other problems, such as mailbox full or attachment max size exceeded.

Comment: exim historically does X-Failed-Recipients too,  but recent version also comply with RFC 3464