# How to handle Delivery Status Notification of GMail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, dsn

1. Does gmail support RFC1892(Delivery Status Notification) ?
2. If so, how can I use JavaMail to parse the DSN. (Sample code is highly appreciated)
3. If not, When a email can't be delivered through gmail, a failure message is returned. How can I detect these "bounced" messages?

Answer (score 1):

1 - I don't know.

2 - Add dsn.jar from JavaMail to your classpath.  Then use something like this:

```
    if (msg.isMimeType("multipart/report")) {
        MultipartReport r = (MultipartReport)msg.getContent();
        // see com.sun.mail.dsn package javadocs for MutlipartReport
    }
```

3 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#bounce

Comment: can post some sample implementation of this

Comment: @Bill, are you able to provide some examples?

Comment: Example of what, exactly?  What are you trying to do?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298285/detecting-if-an-email-is-a-delivery-status-notification-and-extract-informatio/12623903).

The `X-Failed-Recipients` header seems to be the quickest way to identify gmail DSN.  After that, it seems you must parse the text/plain content.

The subject seems to be `Delivery Status Notification (*status*)` where statuses that I've seen are: `Failure`, `Delay`.